# I have a problem with the end of the tutorial djangogirls https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/fr/django_forms/

Tags: python, django-templates

The error message is :

> Template error:
>
> In template H:\djangogirls\blog\templates\blog\base.html, error at line 12
>      Reverse for 'post_new' not found. 'post_new' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

The code and the traceback are available here:
http://dpaste.com/0TSA689

```
views.py
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from django.utils import timezone
from .models import Post
from .forms import PostForm
from django.shortcuts import redirect

def post_list(request):
    posts = Post.objects.filter(published_date__lte=timezone.now()).order_by('published_date')
    return render(request, 'blog/post_list.html', {'posts': posts})

def post_detail(request, pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'blog/post_detail.html', {'post': post})

def post_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = PostForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.author = request.user
            post.published_date = timezone.now()
            post.save()
            return redirect('post_detail', pk=post.pk)
    else:
        form = PostForm()
    return render(request, 'blog/post_edit.html', {'form': form})

urls.py -blog
from django.urls import path 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
]

urls.py -mysite
from django.urls import path
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
]
```

post_detail

{% block content %}

```
<div class="post">

    {% if post.published_date %}

        <div class="date">

            {{ post.published_date }}

        </div>

    {% endif %}

    <h2>{{ post.title }}</h2>

    <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>

</div>
```

{% endblock %}

post list

{% extends 'blog/base.html' %}

{% block content %}

```
{% for post in posts %}

    <div class="post">

        <div class="date">

            {{ post.published_date }}

        </div>

        <h1><a href="{% url 'blog.views.post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">{{ post.title }}</a></h1>

        <p>{{ post.text|linebreaksbr }}</p>

    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

{% endblock content %}

blog base

{% load static %}

```
<head>

    <title>Django Girls blog</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

    <link href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster&subset=latin,latin-ext' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/blog.css' %}">

</head>

<body>

    <div class="page-header">

        <a href="{% url 'post_new' %}" class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>

        <h1><a href="/">Django Girls Blog</a></h1>

    </div>

    <div class="content container">

        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-8">

                {% block content %}

                {% endblock %}

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I would encourage you to edit your post to add your code and error message with proper formatting [explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question). Questions linking to code do not get much attention. For more help with asking, see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The error is expected at this stage. Move onto [the next step](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/fr/django_forms/#url) and you will create the URL pattern and view to fix the error.

Comment: this is still done but the problem persists

Comment: I just added the code of view in the description

Comment: It looks like your `mysite/urls.py` is incorrect, so the URL pattern is not being included. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `mysite/urls.py` is incorrect. You [need to include the urls](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/fr/django_urls/#votre-premi%C3%A8re-url-django-) from your blog app:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

Comment: I don't see why you'd get that error for the code you have posted. Save any open files and restart the server to see if that fixes the problem/changes the error.

Comment: I did it but the problem persists

Comment: Double check that it shows the *exact same* error message as before. The message. In the link you posted, *In template H:\djangogirls\blog\templates\blog\base.html, error at line 6* does not match the template below.

Comment: I would try searching your code/templates for `'blog.views.post_detail'` to try to find where the problem is coming from. Apart from that, I can't help any more because I can't see how the code you have posted would give that error.

Comment: I used the code that is at the begining of this page for base.html : https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/fr/django_forms/

Comment: and i just added the code of blog.view.post-detail in the description

Comment: The error is coming from `/`, which is handled by `views.post_list`. That means the error is in your `'blog/post_list.html'` or `'blog/base.html'` template.

Comment: I just added the code of base and post list in the description. The error message is about line 6 of  the base but i don't understand the problem

Comment: Yes, it's confusing that it says the problem is in `blog/base.html`. The error is actually in `blog/post_list.html`. It should be `<a href="{% url 'post_detail' pk=post.pk %}">`. Here's [the step](https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/fr/extend_your_application/#cr%C3%A9er-un-lien-dans-un-template) in the tutorial. Try to double check your code at each step -- if you make a mistake and find out later, it's trickier to find out where the problem is!

Answer (score 0):

```
 <div class="page-header">
     <a href=" {% url 'post_new' %} " class="top-menu"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></a>
     <h1><a href="/">Django Girls Blog</a></h1>
 </div>
```

Your error is on this part of your code. It looks like in your 'urls.py' file you didn't add the new_post url name so django isn't able to find any url named "post_new". You should edit your urls file to something like this:

```
path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
```

Comment: Would you mind updating your post with the code from your urls.py file?

Comment: from django.urls import path 
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
    path('post/<int:pk>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
    path('post/new/', views.post_new, name='post_new'),
]

Comment: Is the view 'post_new' created?

Comment: I a m new on django, what do you mean exactly by "created"?

Comment: On your views.py file you should have the code like https://tutorial.djangogirls.org/fr/django_forms/#la-vue-postnew. The views are the 'functions' used by django to generate those pages. Your traceback tells us django tried looking for the url named_post new and couldn't call its function. It could be either misspelling (which is not) or something wrong with your views I guess.